# run xrandr commands at startup in Debian Jessie with Gnome 3.14.4

Tags: linux, boot, debian, gnome, xrandr

I try to run this script after boot so I can use the monitor right away.
It works if I run it manually after Gnome started. But putting the commands in `~/.xinitrc` as stated on many pages it does not work.
I also tried putting it in `/etc/init.d` but that did not work either.
Where do I need to put this script to run properly?

```
#! /bin/sh
xrandr --listproviders | grep "number : 2"
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
        xrandr | grep VGA-1-1 | grep "connected"
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                xrandr | grep VGA1 | grep "connected"
                if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                        xrandr --output VGA-1-1 --mode 1280x1024 --rate     75 --right-of VGA1
                fi
        fi
fi
```

Comment: Did you put the contents of the script in your .xinitrc file or did you run the script from .xinitrc? If you did the latter, can you try putting it in your `~/.xsession` file instead?

Comment: I can't login if I put the scriptcode there. I loads something but then goes back to the login screen. I put the contents in .xinitrc and init.d not a call to the script.

Comment: `~/.xinitrc` is supposed to bring in the whole user's X session. GNOME is already bringing you that session so basically when you create this file you telling the X login manager to forget about GNOME and run `~/.xinitrc` expecting it to start everything needed for you to work in X (including window manager etc).  So, did you try what @FinnO'leary suggested?

Comment: ...and it seems, that to do what you want "the GNOME way" you are supposed to use its own "autostart" facility; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8290652/720999) for more info.

Comment: ...and while we're at it, putting such stuff under `/etc/init.d` is absolutely wrong as that hierarchy is intended to control system-wide (that is, non-user) "daemons" (called "services" in a popular OS). X (the graphical desktop) does not work this way. Rather, an X login manager *is* a system daemon by itself; after it starts and presents you with a login prompt, it manages creating/tearing down interactive graphical sessions by itself and scripts under`/etc/init.d` do not get involved in any way.

Comment: Thanks for that info!
Yes I tried what Finn O'leary wrote and as said, if I put the code in .xsession it won't start anymore.

Comment: @kostix the "GNOME way" worked, thanks...could you add that as an answer so I can tag it?

Answer (score 0):

~/.xsessionrc on Debian Jessie is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please extend your answer

Comment: You can put commands in ~/.xsessionrc to run when you login to your desktop environment. This isn't quite the same as running on bootup though (being a per-user setting/config)